# From group by to window function postgres

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

my goal is to compare Event Engagement Rate = ( Event Subscribed / Event Participated ) for the newsletter source vs Email Source by using **window functions**

i Managed to do it by using group by

```
select source ,sum(event_subscribed/event_participated) as "engagement rate"  from events
group by source
```

[image]

i keep failing with the windows function by having too many rows and wrong engagement rates

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In future post please do not post images of your data but formatted text. See "[Why not post images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)"

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand the difference between the `Aggregate functions` and the Window variant of the same function. The aggregate functions builds groups as specified in the 'Group By' clause and reduces the result to a single row per group. The Window version also builds groups as specified in the 'Partition By' clause. However, it does not reduce the number of rows, instead it generated the same result in each of the rows within the group. See [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=57fec2d09e96bf025c4e9cc454b7db45).  To reduce the Window version to a single row per group use [Distinct on](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-select.html) expression.

> SELECT DISTINCT ON ( expression [, ...] ) keeps only the first row of
> each set of rows where the given expressions evaluate to equal. The
> DISTINCT ON expressions are interpreted using the same rules as for
> ORDER BY (see above). Note that the “first row” of each set is
> unpredictable unless ORDER BY is used to ensure that the desired row
> appears first.

Your query becomes

```
select distinct on (source) 
       source 
     , sum(event_subscribed/event_participated) as "engagement rate"  
  from events
 order by source.
```